# g++ errors while compiling object files

Tags: c++, c, linker, makefile

I wrote a small makefile which follows the general structure, creating object files and then linking to create an executable. Here is how it looks..

```
CXX=g++
CXXFLAGS=-Wall -g
INCLUDES= -I ./
LDFLAGS= -L ./
LIBS= -lcryptopp
SRCS= test.cpp
OBJS= $(SRCS:.cpp=.o)
EXEC=test

all: $(EXEC) 

$(EXEC): $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -o $(EXEC) $(OBJS) $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBS)
.cpp.o: 
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c $< -o $@
```

Cryptopp library(cryptopp) is static. Now when I try to run this makefile, when the first command which tries to create object file runs.. its gives me many errors like this..

```
test.cpp:289:   instantiated from here
./include/algparam.h:322: warning: unused variable 'p'
./include/algparam.h: In member function 'void CryptoPP::AlgorithmParametersTemplate<T>::MoveInto(void*) const [with T = unsigned char]':
```

In the end, it links all fine and the executable works but how can I get rid of those warnings without removing `-wall`? I don't have much experience with make and makefiles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not an error, it's a warning.  (Technically, you can consider warnings as errors that don't prevent the compiler from finishing its job.)

And the way you fix it is to fix your code.  This has nothing to do with the makefile.  Delete the variable 'p' from line 322 in ./include/algparam.h.  (There was a bit of a hint in the warning message from the compiler.)

Comment: I updated it(changed errors to warnings). But those header files are provided by cryptopp...wont that be a bad idea changing them?

Comment: If it's open source, make the change and submit it back to the repository.  If you don't want to do that, submit a feature request for the developers to write cleaner code.  (To be honest though, you'll be lucky if that ever happens - open source code quality has never been that great.)  As a last resort you could disable those warnings when including that particular header file.  Most compilers have a way of enabling and disabling warnings within a source file.

Answer (score 0):

for this warning, you can just comment variable `p` in test.cpp or .h file, because you don't use it, or like this

in your code

```
{
...
#ifdef _DEBUG_
xxx p;
#endif
...
}
```

and in your makefile, if you want to use `p`, just add `-D_DEBUG_` in your `CXXFLAGS`